# Question on Wygwam from Pixel & Tonic

Tags: wygwam

We use Wygwam for client to enter their content to EE. Client would like to enter order list type with A,B,C,D instead of 1,2,3,4. Can someone give me a hint how can I add option to client to choose  order list type on the icon bar?

Thanks,
Angela

Answer (score 0):

Following along with the Wygwam documentation you should be able to do this using the style set.
https://docs.pixelandtonic.com/wygwam/using/style_set.html

Your style set code would need to look something like:

```
CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add( 'my_styles',
[
        { name : 'Ordered List', element : 'ol', attributes : { 'class' : 'list-alpha' } },
]);
```

Once you've made your list, highlight it and click the Styles dropdown. You should see your newly created style.
[image]

Once selected if you check the source you should see it attached to the element.

From here you'll need to add some css to that element. Something like:

```
.list-alpha {list-style-type: upper-alpha;}
```

Comment: Thanks Michael! I follow your instructions, I able to see Ordered List, but it overwrite all other Block Styles and Object Styles which is set as default. Do you know how to append instead of overwrite all setting? Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to add those styles to the list-alpha class? I'll look into appending.

Comment: I kind of work around, instead of class, I add type `CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add( 'my_styles',
[
        { name : 'Alpha Ordered List', element : 'ol', attributes : { 'type' : 'a' } }
]);` it shows up as Alphia Ordered List, but it overwrite all default style